# Creating new object in java error

Tags: java, brackets

I wrote this code in the main:

```
if (startAmount>0) //create new cashier object with or without a start amount
    Cashier newCashier = new Cashier(startAmount);
else Cashier newCashier = new Cashier();
```

and got an compile error for the second and third lines:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Cashier cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error on token "newCashier", delete
```

and:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Cashier cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
     Assignment
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
```

but when i write the code like this with brackets:

```
if (startAmount>0)//create new cashier object with or without a start amount
{
    Cashier newCashier = new Cashier(startAmount);
}
else{ Cashier newCashier = new Cashier();}
```

it seems to be okay, no compile errors.
can someone help me understand why?

Comment: Which version of Java and what IDE you use?

Comment: remove the assignment, you don't use the variable `newCashier ` anyway.

Comment: version:Version: Kepler Service Release 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you creating shadow variable for `newCachier` reference, 
you could rather do this

```
Cashier newCashier = null;
if (startAmount>0) //create new cashier object with or without a start amount
    newCashier = new Cashier(startAmount);
else 
     newCashier = new Cashier();
```

Comment: What is the difference between what you wrote and what i wrote?
In both cases was created one object no?

Comment: what do you mean "shadow variable"? it will create only once dependent on the if statement

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to add those curly braces. Cause you won't forget to add them when you extend your code, which leads to strange behavior otherwise.

I think your exception of the first might came cause you forgot to put your else statement in a new line, but I  am not sure.